# Comparison of two String return always false java

Tags: java, string

I have two variable and when i make

```
system.out.println(var1+"  && "+var2)
```

I found this :  "var1" && var2

var1 with quote and var2 without quote so this is why i found always false 
what should i do ??

Comment: Where do these values come from?

Comment: you must give more information about the two variables.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You are concatenating 3 strings there is no expression here that will return `true` or `false`...

Comment: Where is any comparison in your code?

Comment: var1 is string but var2 is value?

Comment: the first variable come from an object with his getter Method and this is with quote 
the second it's constant so i try to do comparision to calculate something but i find always false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should check if the values  you are getting in those variables are correct, and the desired.

If they are correct, then, to delete the quotes you can use the [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method to replace all the double quotes with an empty:

```
var1.replace("\"", "");
```

Note that here you should escape the double quote `\"`.

**Note:** This answer supposes that you are comparing the Strings correctly (using `String#equals`).

Comment: think You bro it work but i don't understand why in one string is with double quotes and the other is without ??

Comment: That has to do in how you are filling the variables `var1` and `var2`. If you post that portion of code, we could tell you.

Comment: the data come from an excel file when i put an other file it work perfectualy       without the method replace but with same file i should use the method that you give it

Comment: Maybe the Excel has some cells with another type. I don't know much about Excel but I have seen that some cells can be given an especial format.

Answer (score 1):

```
system.out.println(var1+"  && "+var2)
```

won't compile, let alone return or result in a value.

&& can not be used for comparisons, it's used to implement the logical AND.

If you want to compare objects, you'll need to use the '==' operator for a referential comparison, or the equals method if you want to compare values.

For String instances, you have an additional equalsIgnoreCase method you can use.

so: if var1 and var2 are objects, you can try this:

```
System.out.println((var1 == var2)); // compare references
```

and

```
System.out.println(var1.equals(var2)); // compare values
```

If they are primitives, you'll need to use the '==' operator

If they are booleans you want to check:

```
System.out.println(var1&&var2);
```

will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
    String intint = "INT";
    String gouc = "GOUc";
    String fg2a = "FG2c";
    String fg2c = "FG2c";
    String goua = "GOUa";
    affichageBroadInfos(broadInfos);

    Iterator<RncBroadInfo> iter = broadInfos.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        RncBroadInfo str = iter.next();
    //    if (!(str.getBroadClass().equals("INT"))) { this return false

        if (!(str.getBroadClass().replace("\"", "").equals(intint))) {

            System.out.println("ToComprare Twoe Strings " + str.getBroadClass().replace("\"", "") + " && " + intint);
            System.out.println("To Remove Interface" + str.toString());
            System.out.println("type var 1" + str.getBroadClass().getClass());
            System.out.println("type var 2" + intint.getClass());
            System.out.println("result of Comparision " + str.getBroadClass().equals(intint));

            iter.remove();
        }
    }
```